# Tesseract-OCR Cannot resolve corresponding JNI function

Tags: android, android-studio, tesseract

I have to use tesseract-ocr in Android Studio but I get an error.

```
04-10 22:04:56.885 17764-17764/com.example.samsung.bitirme_deneme3 V/Tesseract(native): Java_com_googlecode_tesseract_android_TessBaseAPI_nativeClassInit
04-10 22:04:56.885 17764-17764/com.example.samsung.bitirme_deneme3 W/dalvikvm: Exception Ljava/lang/NoSuchFieldError; thrown while initializing Lcom/googlecode/tesseract/android/TessBaseAPI;
04-10 22:04:56.885 17764-17764/com.example.samsung.bitirme_deneme3 W/dalvikvm: threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x41b25a08)
04-10 22:04:56.915 17764-17764/com.example.samsung.bitirme_deneme3 E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
04-10 22:04:56.915 17764-17764/com.example.samsung.bitirme_deneme3 E/AndroidRuntime: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
04-10 22:04:56.915 17764-17764/com.example.samsung.bitirme_deneme3 E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.example.samsung.bitirme_deneme3.MainActivity$1.onClick(MainActivity.java:555)
04-10 22:04:56.915 17764-17764/com.example.samsung.bitirme_deneme3 E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4231)
04-10 22:04:56.915 17764-17764/com.example.samsung.bitirme_deneme3 E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17537)
04-10 22:04:56.915 17764-17764/com.example.samsung.bitirme_deneme3 E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:725)
04-10 22:04:56.915 17764-17764/com.example.samsung.bitirme_deneme3 E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
04-10 22:04:56.915 17764-17764/com.example.samsung.bitirme_deneme3 E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:158)
04-10 22:04:56.915 17764-17764/com.example.samsung.bitirme_deneme3 E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5751)
04-10 22:04:56.915 17764-17764/com.example.samsung.bitirme_deneme3 E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-10 22:04:56.915 17764-17764/com.example.samsung.bitirme_deneme3 E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
04-10 22:04:56.915 17764-17764/com.example.samsung.bitirme_deneme3 E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1083)
04-10 22:04:56.915 17764-17764/com.example.samsung.bitirme_deneme3 E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:850)
04-10 22:04:56.915 17764-17764/com.example.samsung.bitirme_deneme3 E/AndroidRuntime:     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
04-10 22:04:56.915 17764-17764/com.example.samsung.bitirme_deneme3 E/AndroidRuntime:  Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: no field with name='mNativeData' signature='I' in class Lcom/googlecode/tesseract/android/TessBaseAPI;
04-10 22:04:56.915 17764-17764/com.example.samsung.bitirme_deneme3 E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.googlecode.tesseract.android.TessBaseAPI.nativeClassInit(Native Method)
04-10 22:04:56.915 17764-17764/com.example.samsung.bitirme_deneme3 E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.googlecode.tesseract.android.TessBaseAPI.<clinit>(TessBaseAPI.java:47)
04-10 22:04:56.915 17764-17764/com.example.samsung.bitirme_deneme3 E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.example.samsung.bitirme_deneme3.MainActivity$1.onClick(MainActivity.java:555) 
04-10 22:04:56.915 17764-17764/com.example.samsung.bitirme_deneme3 E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4231) 
04-10 22:04:56.915 17764-17764/com.example.samsung.bitirme_deneme3 E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17537) 
04-10 22:04:56.915 17764-17764/com.example.samsung.bitirme_deneme3 E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:725) 
04-10 22:04:56.915 17764-17764/com.example.samsung.bitirme_deneme3 E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92) 
04-10 22:04:56.915 17764-17764/com.example.samsung.bitirme_deneme3 E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:158) 
04-10 22:04:56.915 17764-17764/com.example.samsung.bitirme_deneme3 E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5751) 
04-10 22:04:56.915 17764-17764/com.example.samsung.bitirme_deneme3 E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
04-10 22:04:56.915 17764-17764/com.example.samsung.bitirme_deneme3 E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511) 
04-10 22:04:56.915 17764-17764/com.example.samsung.bitirme_deneme3 E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1083) 
04-10 22:04:56.915 17764-17764/com.example.samsung.bitirme_deneme3 E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:850) 
04-10 22:04:56.915 17764-17764/com.example.samsung.bitirme_deneme3 E/AndroidRuntime:     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

**Line 47 in TessBaseAPI.java:** nativeClassInit();

In TessBaseAPI.java class, When I came over nativeClassInit() function, an error seems: *

> Cannot resolve corresponding JNI function
>   Java_com_googlecode_tesseract_android_TessBaseAPI_nativeClassInit(),
>
> Reports native method declarations in Java where no corresponding JNI
>   function is found in the project.

*

But the function "nativeClassInit()" is defined in tessbaseapi.cpp:

> void
>   Java_com_googlecode_tesseract_android_TessBaseAPI_nativeClassInit(JNIEnv*
>   env, 
>                                                                          jclass clazz) {
>
> field_mNativeData = env->GetFieldID(clazz, "mNativeData", "J");
>   method_onProgressValues = env->GetMethodID(clazz, "onProgressValues",
>   "(IIIIIIIII)V"); }

I found some solutions but the problem didn't fix. Thank you for your help.

Comment: The precompiled shared object files you're using are too old. See the "Usage" section [here](https://github.com/rmtheis/tess-two#usage) for proper usage.

Comment: I did but I get another error:

"Error:Execution failed for task ':app:dexDebug'.
> com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command 'C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_25\bin\java.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 2"

Comment: You should ask that as a new question, including all the details and steps to reproduce the error.